# How to convert the Excel 2007 Macro: "ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie" into C++/VB 2005 Code?

Tags: c++, excel, automation

To everyone,

I've been searching but barely find any answers. I've been trying to convert this macro:

```
Range("A1:B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$7")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
```

For Excel 2007 which makes a simple 2D Pie chart out of the data from cells A1 to B7.

Here is how I converted it into C++ code implementing the Autowrap functions:

-------MISCELLANEOUS CODE-------------

```
VARIANT darange;

IDispatch *pXlRange;
{  
VARIANT range;
range.vt = VT_BSTR;
range.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"A1:B7");
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlSheet, L"Range", 1, range);
darange.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
darange.pdispVal = result.pdispVal;
pXlRange = result.pdispVal;
}

{
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pXlRange, L"Select", 0);
}

IDispatch *pXlChartObjects;
{
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlSheet, L"Shapes", 0);
pXlChartObjects = result.pdispVal;
}

IDispatch *pXlChartObject;
{
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
VARIANT left, top, width, height;
left.vt = VT_R8;
left.dblVal = 600.;
top.vt = VT_R8;
top.dblVal = 600.;
width.vt = VT_R8;
width.dblVal = 200.;
height.vt = VT_R8;
height.dblVal = 200.;

AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pXlChartObjects, L"AddChart", 1, left, top, width, height);
pXlChartObject = result.pdispVal;
}

{                              
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pXlRange, L"Select", 0);
}


IDispatch *pXlChart;
{
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);

AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlChartObject, L"Chart", 0);
pXlChart = result.pdispVal;
}


// NOT WORKING
{
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
VARIANT type;
type.vt = VT_BSTR;
type.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"xlPie");
//type.vt = VT_I4;
//type.lVal = 75;
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, &result, pXlChart, L"Chartype", 1, type);
}
// NOT WORKING

{
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);

AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pXlChart, L"SetSourceData", 1, darange);
}

/*
```

-------MISCELLANEOUS CODE----------

It opens Excel and generates a bar graph fine, but I need a Pie chart for my implementation. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to pass "xlPie" to this piece of code:

```
// NOT WORKING
{
VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);
VARIANT type;
type.vt = VT_BSTR;
type.bstrVal = ::SysAllocString(L"xlPie");
//type.vt = VT_I4;
//type.lVal = 75;
AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, &result, pXlChart, L"Chartype", 1, type);
}
// NOT WORKING
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlPie` is a numeric constant, *not* a string. Get its value by typing `debug.print xlPie` in the VBA immediate window. Define it in your C++ as (I think) a long type. Then pass it.

Don't convert it to a BSTR.

(Also, don't forget to free your BSTRs using ::SysFreeString or you'll get memory leaks).

Comment: Many thanks! Found the right value for it and realized that

AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, &result, pXlChart, L"Chartype", 1, type);

Had the word "ChartType" incorrectly written as "Chartype". Thanks!